# Looking for a rare paper

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for the rare paper " Shinziro Mori, Allgemeine Z.P.I.-Ringe, J. Sci. Hirosima Univ. Ser. A. 10 (1940), 117–136. ". Can anyone help me to find it or any help?

Comment: Most university libraries have Interlibrary loan (ILL).

Comment: Its journal is not in the list of the libraries that I know. I guess its  journal is not available anywhere. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I would request it via Interlibrary loan and let librarians worry how to get it. They may of course fail.

Comment: It is not your business to locate it in the catalogs. This is done by Interlibrary loan specialists. I just checked: it is in the catalog of my library, but we do not have the volume you need. ILL specialists will know where to get it from.

Comment: In my experience, ILL specialists NEVER failed. They form a network and can ask each other. Once they even found for me a paper in a journal which existed for less than one year during the civil war in Russia:-)

Comment: Our ILL department could not locate for me a publication of Yarolval' University from the 70s. It was not even reviewed in MR, only in Zbl. Eventually I got it from via personal connections.

Comment: Thanks dear Alexandre Eremenko  and Igor Belegradek  for your time and help.

Comment: The University of Michigan has the most complete math collection of any university math library in the United States (due to historical reasons), so it is usually a good idea to contact their math librarian when such a dilemma arises (or to suggest your ILL person contact them). They have physical copies of that journal going back to the beginning, with some gaps among volumes 10--17 (perhaps due to WWII), and have part of volume 10:  http://mirlyn.lib.umich.edu/Record/000535146/Holdings#1  Maybe pp. 117--136 is low enough to be part of the volume 10 that they have?

Comment: Hathitrust has scanned the University of Michigan copy of volume 10, and the [limited search](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015038755206) that it offers shows that the article by Mori is indeed there.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Ah, that was clever idea for how to confirm it.  So UM math library comes through as desired.  Go Blue!

Answer (score 3):

This does not appear to be available online as the (now) [Hiroshima Mathematical Journal](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/hmj/) only offers volumes from 2000 onwards, so you will need to look for a hard copy.

The title is [available in WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/journal-of-science-of-the-hiroshima-university-series-a-mathematics-physics-chemistry-vol-1-no-3-etc-october-1931-etc/oclc/560666990?referer=brief_results), which in my experience tends to have accurate results of the libraries near you that have the title. If one of those is near you, the simplest thing might be to just go there. If they are too far to travel, the next thing to try is inter-library loan, as mentioned in the comments, for which you should consult your institution's librarian (or the nearest public library if you're independent).